# Replace PolygonCollider2D with MeshCollider at runtime

Tags: unity, c#, meshcollider

I am using a PolygonCollider2D to load in points for a MeshCollider at runtime, but am having issues switching between the two at runtime using good coding practices.

This is a simplified version of the current code:

```
Awake(){
    PolygonCollider2D polyCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    //save vectors
    Vector3[] v3 = new Vector3[polyCollider.points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < polyCollider.points.Length; i++)
    {
        v3[i] = new Vector3(polyCollider .points[i].x, polyCollider .points[i].y, 0);
    }
    //destroy collider
    DestroyImmediate(collider);
    meshCollider = this.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    meshCollider.sharedMesh.vertices = v3;
}
```

Other than the bad naming, how can I substitute DestroyImmediate(collider) with Destory(collider) while still having it behave correctly. I would be willing to move the mesh collider declaration to a different function to delay its assignment.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is it not replacing the collider, is it only deleting the collider, is it throwing an error, etc?

Comment: it does not remove the PlygonCollider2D in time for it to add the MeshCollider because both cannot be active at once.

Comment: Have you tried putting the adding of the new one into Start instead of Awake?

Comment: I'm worried that that wont be consistent if it is on a slow machine

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure filling `sharedMesh.vertices` will be enough to convert your `PolygonCollider2D` into a `MeshCollider`.

From my (not long enough and too basic) tests, when you try to create a `MeshCollider` and only give it vertices it doesn't work. Your `MeshCollider` will need vertices but also **triangles**.

After getting the polygon points you might have to compute all the triangles to recompose the shape.

Comment: I forgot to add that part. I am also generating the indices. That is not the issue. The issue is that the collider is not destroyed before the other one is made.

Comment: Then, have you tried to create an actual Mesh and set it to ``meshCollider.sharedMesh`` instead of filling the vertices / tris alone?

Comment: Yes, there were some issues with this that I just solved, but that was still not the issue, I will be posting the solution here in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to use a Coroutine that waits for the variable to be destroyed. This guarantees that it will be able to make the MeshCollider. Here is a piece of sample code that could be used to implement a similar solution.

```
Vector3[] v3
IEnumerator Start(){
    PolygonCollider2D polyCollider = this.gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    //save vectors
    v3 = new Vector3[polyCollider.points.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < polyCollider.points.Length; i++)
    {
        v3[i] = new Vector3(polyCollider .points[i].x, polyCollider .points[i].y, 0);
    }
    //destroy collider
    DestroyImmediate(collider);

    yield return StartCoroutine(genearteMeshCollider());
}

IEnumerator genearteMeshCollider()
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => this.polygonCollider == null);
    meshCollider = this.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    meshCollider.sharedMesh.vertices = v3;
    setIndecies(meshCollider.sharedMesh.vertices);
}
```

This code needed to be moved to Start because IEnmerators cannot be on the Awake function.